# Menu link areas not aligned with text [wordpress]

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hyperlink

After playing around with my header and and main menu it seems the link box is not actually aligned with the text. I tried playing around with margins and padding but I can't seem to get it to work or find the right class. I would like to keep everything where it is currently and just move the link areas to the right so everything aligns. Any input is appreciated.

Website: http://museiam.ca/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have:

```
.main-navigation ul li a, .menu_centered_style .gbtr_first_menu li
{
    left: 40px;
}
```

Removing the `left: 40px;` should fix this.

EDIT: Try adding the following styles

```
.menu_centered_style .gbtr_first_menu ul 
{
    margin-left: 108px;
}

.menu_centered_style .gbtr_first_menu .shopping_bag_centered_style_wrapper 
{
    margin-left: -24px;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I added left:40px; though to kind of center the menu more. Unless there is a better way to center it without causing this issue I'd love to know. If not, is there a way to bring the links over to the right more?

Comment: After removing the left: 40px; and adding those tweaks everything aligns great. Thanks so much!